# ExpressJS & Mongoose Schema embedding with DBRef examples

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, express

I'd love to collect/see any code examples or links to such using ExpressJS & Mongoose that show Schema embedding, saving/updating with DBRefs. Simple usecase:

Comments on a Blog Post with DBRefs to Users in the Blog Post and Each Comment, showing saving/updating, and maybe as an extra treat: getters, setters, and a virtual or 2 tallying total comments or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue open about this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues#issue/188

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at 
https://github.com/jspears/mojaba
and https://github.com/jspears/mers

Mers exposes Mongoose Schema as JSON/REST in the expressjs framework and Mojaba creates CRUD operations for mongoose schemas.  I am working on making mojaba an express plugin so all you have to do is add your schema and you get a fully functioning crud thing, but that's not quite done yet.

Its a little rough but should work.

Comment: interesting, while it doesn't seem related to the above question it certainly sounds useful!